# Does True Seeing work through Scrying?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light

Some wise guy decided to cast Scrying on me while I was standing in a truly excessively bright place such that I had to cast True Seeing to see my own hands. The sensor was blinded immediately as a matter of course.

Undeterred, he cast True Seeing and then Scrying again. At least I think that's what he did. I had no trouble observing the sensor disappear and reappear thanks to True Seeing.

Does this even make sense? Does True Seeing propagate to the Scrying sensor?

Is now a good time to ready an action against Scry and Fry? I keep a certain spell prepared for just such an occasion but holding a readied action keeps me from my work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, it does work

The deciding part is this sentence in the description of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell:

> You can see and hear through the sensor **as if you were there.**

If you were there, while affected by *true seeing*, could you see and hear into the Ethereal Plane, see invisible creatures and objects, and see through illusions? Yes, so the benefits of *true seeing* extend to vision and hearing from the *scrying* sensor.

---

*True seeing* and truesight do not allow you to see in excessively bright places, so unless it is house-ruled, you might have used it wrong.

Comment: Jeremy Crawford confirms that any senses you have are applied to the scrying sensor as well, in his response to a question in this 2/6/19 Dragon+ segment at 22 minutes in: https://youtu.be/jaWXQEpOtAg?t=1320