# Can I cast the Scrying spell to see from places I've only seen using the Scrying spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, vision-and-light, targeting

The [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell allows you to place an invisible sensor anywhere you've seen before. You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there

Imagine this scenario: I've seen the top of a mountain from far before, so I decide to use *scrying* to create a sensor there. From the top of the mountain using the sensor, I can see the top of another mountain and I later use *scrying* to see from the top of that mountain, and so forth.

As written it seems that "seeing" a location using the *scrying* spell allows you to subsequently see **from** that location using the *scrying* spell. Is this correct?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to attack enemies through a scrying sensor?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/97951)

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're asking "If I see a location using *scrying*, can I cast *scrying* again and create a new sensor at the location I saw before?"

Comment: @Rubiksmoose since Scrying obviously doesn't require a clear path to the target (otherwise it would be goddamn useless), I think the linked question is at best tangential to this one.

Comment: Semi-related: [Does True Seeing work through Scrying?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138506/does-true-seeing-work-through-scrying)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Yes, you can.

The part of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell description about targeting a location says:

> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose **a location you have seen before** as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

It doesn't specify that you must have seen the location physically; any form of "sight" is enough. It's a concentration spell, so you can't have multiple castings of *scrying* active at the same time, but you don't need to - you just need to have seen it at some earlier point. And per the earlier portion of the spell description:

> You can see and hear through the sensor as if you were there. [...] A creature that can see invisible objects sees the sensor as a luminous orb about the size of your fist.

As such, from a straightforward reading of the spell, you can indeed choose a location you have previously seen through the scrying sensor as the target for a new *scrying* spell.

The spell description doesn't specify how closely you must have seen the location, or how specific the location you choose must be. As such, this is something that's left to the DM to adjudicate.

Comment: This is how we ruled and I figured this was the answer! Thank you. Just seemed a bit strange that I could see the entire world using scrying, but I guess it is a level 5 spell, so maybe its not that crazy. I was able to track down some pretty bad dudes.

Comment: Note that the location-targeting version of *scrying* creates an unmoving sensor. But yeah, most people in the world don't have any class level or any spellcasting ability at all; adventurers (and bad guys) are a rarity. And most competent bad guys have countermeasures for such things :)